# How do I launch a site on Chrome/Firefox by pressing a key or preferably 2 keys

Tags: javascript

I have this keyboard site launcher script, which I copied from some place years ago and it works fine as is. I want to enhance it by adding a cascading keypress launch for some of the keys. Here is my code:

```
<html><head>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
var key = new Array();
key['a'] = "https://www.arstechnica.com";
key['g'] = "https://www.google.com";
key['s'] = "https://slashdot.org";
key['y'] = "http://www.yahoo.com";
function getKey(keyStroke) {
isNetscape=(document.layers);
eventChooser = (isNetscape) ? keyStroke.which : event.keyCode;
which = String.fromCharCode(eventChooser).toLowerCase();
// alert('['+which+'] key \n has been stroke');
runUrl(which);
}
function runUrl(which) {
for (var i in key) 
       if (which == i) {window.location = key[i];}
}
document.onkeypress = getKey;
//  End -->
</script></head>
<body>
Make a selection<br>
<br>
key['a'] = "https://www.arstechnica.com";
key['g'] = "https://www.google.com";
key['s'] = "https://slashdot.org";
key['y'] = "http://www.yahoo.com";
<br>
<br>
<!-- I solemnly swear this page is coded with vi or notepad.exe depending on the OS being used -->
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I want to modify the action for pressing the letter "s" to launch a submenu of sorts and ask me to select if I want to go to "Slashdot" or Spotify" for instance. like if I press an "s" second time, it goes to slashdot and if I press "f" for instance, it goes to spotify.

My problem is, I have never programmed in Javascript other than copying and pasting code and changing string values in the code, like here, changing the pressed keys and site URLs.

Any pointers, regarding how to start modifying this code, are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

to be honest, the code provided is a bit outdated but I keep it so you can see the necessary changes that I made for the menu to be added and to implement the feature it's just a sketch but I will do the job I think from here you can expand, hope this puts you in the right direction

```js
let isopenMenu = true;
const menu = document.getElementById("menu");

function toggleMenu() {
  isopenMenu = !isopenMenu;
  menu.style.display = isopenMenu ? "block" : "none";
}
var key = new Array();
key["a"] = "https://www.arstechnica.com";
key["g"] = "https://www.google.com";
key["s"] = "https://slashdot.org";
key["y"] = "http://www.yahoo.com";
key["b"] = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
key["c"] = "http://www.test.com";

const menuSite = ["b", "c", "s"];

function getKey(keyStroke) {
  isNetscape = document.layers;
  eventChooser = isNetscape ? keyStroke.which : event.keyCode;
  which = String.fromCharCode(eventChooser).toLowerCase();
  runUrl(which);
}
function runUrl(which) {
  for (var i in key)
    if (which == i) {
      if (which === "s") {
        return toggleMenu();
      }
      if (!isopenMenu && menuSite.includes(which)) {
        return;
      }
      window.location = key[i];
    }
}
document.onkeypress = getKey;
window.addEventListener("load", toggleMenu);
```

```html
<html><head>
<script language="JavaScript">

</script></head>
<body>
Make a selection<br>
<br>
key['a'] = "https://www.arstechnica.com";
key['g'] = "https://www.google.com";
key['s'] = "to toggel menu
key['y'] = "http://www.yahoo.com";
<br>
<br>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>key['b'] = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";</li>
  <li>key['c'] = "http://www.test.com</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the code you've provided seems a bit dusted. There's some stuff that isn't done in that way nowadays. Notepad is an editor I still occassionally use though.

Since you've mentioned that you never really used JavaScript it's a bit hard to give you advice. You can do things way more elegant and even improve the look - but I'd say this would just confuse you even more. So let's work on something based on your code.

At the moment the keys and the corresponding targets are stored in an object (yeah, it's an object not an array). We can use a second object - let' say `subKey` - to store the additional targets upon pressing **s**.

```
var key = {};
key.a = "https://www.arstechnica.com";
key.g = "https://www.google.com";
key.s = "subMenu";
key.y = "http://www.yahoo.com";

var subKey = {};
subKey.a = "https://www.stackoverflow.com";
subKey.g = "https://www.startpage.com";
subKey.s = "goBack";
```

As you can see I've reserved the key **s** to go to the sub menu and inside the sub menu this button is used to go back to the main menu.

Now instead of hardcoding what the user gets to see on screen, we can iterate over those objects and use the information from there. To do this we need to reserve a html element - I've chosen an empty `<div>` which acts as some sort of container. As we iterate over the object we construct a string with the keys and it's associated targets and ultimately assign this this to the div's `.innerHTML` property.

```
  let container = document.getElementById("container");
  container.innerHTML = "Make a selection<br><br>";
  for (var i in obj) {
    container.innerHTML += "key['" + i + "'] = " + obj[i] + "<br>";
  }
```

As the procedure is the same for both objects we just need to wrap it inside a function and pass it a reference to the desired object.

Your runUrl function needs to be modified a bit to take care of the additional options. This is best done with a simple if-else construct. So in pseudo-code:

- if choice is subMenu open sub menu
- if choice is goBack open main menu
- if it's none of the above open a link

If we put everything together, your example looks a little bit like this:
(Just click on 'Run code snippet' and make sure to click somewhere inside the window so it'll have key focus)

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var key = {};
  key.a = "https://www.arstechnica.com";
  key.g = "https://www.google.com";
  key.s = "subMenu";
  key.y = "http://www.yahoo.com";

  var subKey = {};
  subKey.a = "https://www.stackoverflow.com";
  subKey.g = "https://www.startpage.com";
  subKey.s = "goBack";

  var currentObj = key;

  function getKey(event) {
    let which = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();
    runUrl(which)
  }

  function runUrl(which) {
    for (var i in currentObj) {
      if (which == i) {
        if (currentObj[i] != "subMenu") {
          if (currentObj[i] != "goBack") {
            window.location = currentObj[i];
          } else {
            populateMenu(key);
          }
        } else {
          populateMenu(subKey);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function populateMenu(obj) {
    currentObj = obj;
    let container = document.getElementById("container");
    container.innerHTML = "Make a selection<br><br>";
    for (var i in obj) {
      container.innerHTML += "key['" + i + "'] = " + obj[i] + "<br>";
    }
  }
  populateMenu(key);
  document.onkeypress = getKey;
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like could achieve this with arbitrary list of sites. If so, you could handle this a little more generically by providing a list of sites and filtering the sites based on keystrokes.

If so, you can achieve it with the following:

```js
const sites = [
  'https://www.arstechnica.com',
  'https://www.google.com',
  'https://mail.google.com',
  'https://slashdot.org',
  'https://spotify.com',
  'http://www.yahoo.com',
];

let matches = sites;
document.getElementById('keys').addEventListener('keyup', event => {
  const keys = event.target.value.toLowerCase().split('');

  matches = sites
    .map(site => ({ site, stripped: site.replace(/^https?:\/\/(www\.)?/i, '')})) // strip out https://wwww. prefix
    .filter(site => isMatch(site.stripped, keys))
    .map(site => site.site);
      
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    if (matches.length === 0) {
      alert('No matches');
    } else if (matches.length === 1) {
      alert(`launching ${matches[0]}`);
    } else {
      alert('More than one match found');
    }
    matches = sites;
  }
  
  document.getElementById('matches').textContent = matches.join(', ');
});

// find sites matching keys
function isMatch(site, keys) {
  if (keys.length === 0) return true;
  if (site.indexOf(keys[0]) !== 0) return false;
  
  let startIndex = 1;
  for (let i = 1; i < keys.length; i++) {
    let index = site.indexOf(keys[i], startIndex);
    if (index === -1) return false;
    startIndex = index + 1;
  }
  return true;
}

document.getElementById('matches').textContent = matches.join(', ');
```

```html
<div>Keys: <input type="text" id="keys" autocomplete="off" /> press Enter to launch.</div>
<p>Matches: <span id="matches" /></p>
```

The key parts to this are:

1. Define a list of sites you want to handle
2. Ignore the the `https://wwww` prefixes which is achieved with `site.replace(/^https?:\/\/(www\.)?/i, '')`
3. Implement filter logic (in this case it is the `isMatch` method) which tries to match multiple keystrokes
4. For demonstration purposes, I've wired `keyup` to an input field instead of `document` so that you can see it in action, and the action is triggered with the enter/return key.